# How to update array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I don't know whether this question has been asked before. However, I need to ask this to get help from you guys:

I have a document like below:

```
{
    "taskboard_id": "6149a3de8f604511e6883bae",
    "user_id": "61399af5d6294f56aa1116f0",
    "task_groups": [{
        "task_group_id": "614975a0e8fad7ef68561b36",
        "task_id": "614869a706ff00ab459460e5",
        "is_completed": true,
        "completion_date":"2021-10-07T05:04:50.760Z",
    },
    {
        "task_group_id": "614975a0e8fad7ef68561b37",
        "task_id": "614869a706ff00ab459460e5",
        "is_completed": false,
        "completion_date":"",
    }]
}
```

The difference between the array of two objects is the `task_group_id`.
Now I want to update the `is_completed` and `completion_date` by `taskboard_id`, `user_id`, `"task_groups.task_group_id"` and `"task_groups. task_id"`. And below is my query:

```
db.task_status.updateOne(
{
        user_id: new ObjectId(payload.user_id),
        taskboard_id: new ObjectId(payload.taskboard_id),
        "task_groups.task_group_id": new ObjectId(payload.task_group_id),
        "task_groups.task_id": new ObjectId(payload.task_id),
 },
 $set: {
          "task_groups.$.is_completed": payload.is_completed,
          "task_groups.$.completion_date": new Date(),
 },
);
```

The problem is whenever I try to update the first object is updated fine but whenever it comes to the second one it doesn't update.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you checked whether [$\[\]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---) operator is what you are looking for?

Comment: @ray it is updating all objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `arrayfilter` in `update`

```
db.collection.update({
  user_id: "61399af5d6294f56aa1116f0",
  taskboard_id: "6149a3de8f604511e6883bae",
  "task_groups.task_group_id": "614975a0e8fad7ef68561b37",
  "task_groups.task_id": "614869a706ff00ab459460e5",
  
},
{
  "$set": {
    "task_groups.$[item].is_completed": true,
    "task_groups.$[item].completion_date": new Date(),
    
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "item.task_group_id": {
        $eq: "614975a0e8fad7ef68561b37"
      },
      "item.task_id": {
        $eq: "614869a706ff00ab459460e5"
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-a1A5Z9Vlrd)